# Can AWS Cloud Front get data returned by REST API

Tags: java, amazon-cloudfront

I want to have our server as origin for Cloud Front. When CF cannot get data in cache, then it will call REST API in our server to download the file.

I've read many CF docs but it only mentions that CF can get specific file path in server rather than REST API result.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is very much possible.This is how CloudFront deliver content

After you configure CloudFront to deliver your content, here's what happens when users request your files:

- A user accesses your website or application and requests one or more
  files, such as an image file and an HTML file.
- DNS routes the request to the CloudFront POP (edge location) that can
  best serve the request—typically the nearest CloudFront POP in terms
  of latency—and routes the request to that edge location.
- In the POP, CloudFront checks its cache for the requested files. If
  the files are in the cache, CloudFront returns them to the user. **If
  the files are not in the cache, it does the following:**

  - **CloudFront compares the request with the specifications in your

    distribution and forwards the request for the files to your origin

    server for the corresponding file type—for example, to your Amazon S3
    bucket for image files and to your HTTP server for HTML files.**
  - The origin servers send the files back to the edge location.
  - As soon as the first byte arrives from the origin, CloudFront begins
    to forward the files to the user. CloudFront also adds the files to
    the cache in the edge location for the next time someone requests
    those files.

[Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HowCloudFrontWorks.html) you can get the details how content delivery work.